# How to use a variable inside a regular expression

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, variables, escaping

I'd like to use a variable inside a regex, how can I do this in Python?

```
TEXTO = sys.argv[1]

if re.search(r"\b(?=\w)TEXTO\b(?!\w)", subject, re.IGNORECASE):
    # Successful match
else:
    # Match attempt failed
```

Comment: You use string concatenation

Answer (score 238, accepted):

From python 3.6 on you can also use [Literal String Interpolation](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/), "f-strings". In your particular case the solution would be:

```
if re.search(rf"\b(?=\w){TEXTO}\b(?!\w)", subject, re.IGNORECASE):
    ...do something
```

EDIT:

Since there have been some questions in the comment on how to deal with special characters I'd like to extend my answer:

**raw strings ('r'):**

One of the main concepts you have to understand when dealing with special characters in regular expressions is to distinguish between string literals and the regular expression itself. It is very well explained [here](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html#the-backslash-plague):

In short:

Let's say instead of finding a word boundary `\b` after `TEXTO` you want to match the string `\boundary`. The you have to write:

```
TEXTO = "Var"
subject = r"Var\boundary"

if re.search(rf"\b(?=\w){TEXTO}\\boundary(?!\w)", subject, re.IGNORECASE):
    print("match")
```

This only works because we are using a raw-string (the regex is preceded by 'r'), otherwise we must write "\\\\boundary" in the regex (four backslashes). Additionally, without '\r', \b' would not converted to a word boundary anymore but to a backspace!

**re.escape**:

Basically puts a backslash in front of any special character. Hence, if you expect a special character in TEXTO, you need to write:

```
if re.search(rf"\b(?=\w){re.escape(TEXTO)}\b(?!\w)", subject, re.IGNORECASE):
    print("match")
```

NOTE: For any version >= python 3.7: `!`, `"`, `%`, `'`, `,`, `/`, `:`, `;`, `<`, `=`, `>`, `@`, and `` ` `` are not escaped. Only special characters with meaning in a regex are still escaped. `_` is not escaped since Python 3.3.(s. [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.escape))

**Curly braces:**

If you want to use quantifiers within the regular expression using f-strings, you have to use double curly braces. Let's say you want to match TEXTO followed by exactly 2 digits:

```
if re.search(rf"\b(?=\w){re.escape(TEXTO)}\d{{2}}\b(?!\w)", subject, re.IGNORECASE):
    print("match")
```

Comment: As of 2020, this is the simplest and most pythonic way to use a variable inside a regular expression

Comment: This is definitely a **WOW**.

Comment: can someone explain the significance of "rf" here

Comment: @HarshaReddy: 'r': This string is a raw string: If you don't use it, '\b' will be converted to the backspace character (https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html#more-pattern-power). 'f' tells python that this is an 'f-string', s. link above, and enables you to write the variable into the curly braces-

Comment: Does this escape special characters in the substituted string? Just from a little testing, it doesn't seem to. `re.escape()` is still required

Comment: @Tugzrida: yes, of course if you expect user input containing special characters you need to write "if re.search(rf"\b(?=\w){re.escape(TEXTO)}\b(?!\w)", subject, re.IGNORECASE)". The 'r' only tells python that the literal string is raw. "re.escape" basically puts a backslash in front of every special character.

Comment: How to write quantifiers in f-strings: `fr"foo{{1,5}}"` (double the braces)

Comment: For python >=3.6 the chars you wrote are not escaped.I would say they **do not have to be escaped**. If you want to have a dot instead, you still (also in new Python versions) have to escape it with `\.`

Comment: I got : `splitter = 1;str_='unbenannt.png28.png';mat =re.match(f'unbenannt\.png\d{{splitter}}\.png$', str_)` that does not grasp the string. This works: `    mat = re.match('unbenannt\.png\d{'+str(splitter)+'}\.png$', str_)`

Comment: In quantifiers one can split the regex string `r"[a-f]{1," f"{max}" r"}"`

Comment: @Timo: No, they are not escaped! My comment refers to re.escape. re.escape('.') outputs '\\.'. re.escape(':') outputs ':'. Try it out in the python console if you don't believe me. (>=3.7 as stated).

Comment: @airborne Awesome.. U explained it very well in detailed. This answer helped me a lot. Thank you so much. I appreciate you for your detailed desription. Never knew that just combining raw-string and f-string is possible and can be used with a variable. Definitely a salute to your explanation!

Comment: @airborne, do you mean "backslash" instead of "backspace" in your description of **re.escape**?

Answer (score 350):

You have to build the regex as a string:

```
TEXTO = sys.argv[1]
my_regex = r"\b(?=\w)" + re.escape(TEXTO) + r"\b(?!\w)"

if re.search(my_regex, subject, re.IGNORECASE):
    etc.
```

Note the use of `re.escape` so that if your text has special characters, they won't be interpreted as such.

Comment: What if your variable goes first? `r'' + foo + 'bar'` ?

Comment: @deed02392 `r''` not necessary if you do `re.escape(foo)`, which you should anyway. Actually, I think `re` interprets whatever it's given as a unicode string regardless of whether you prefix `r` or not.

Comment: Does .format() work as well in place of the re.escape or is re.escape() necessary?

Comment: @praxiteles did u find the answer?

Comment: I'm not sure if this works in I need to have a group of which the variable is a part of. Other answers below look more intuitive for that, and don't break the regex into several expressions.

Comment: The r'' just tells Python to treat its content as 'raw', else you'd need to escape backslashes etc. See https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html#the-backslash-plague It's not needed to use any r'' for building a regex, though.

Comment: r means a raw string.  regular expressions use raw strings

Answer (score 55):

```
if re.search(r"\b(?<=\w)%s\b(?!\w)" % TEXTO, subject, re.IGNORECASE):
```

This will insert what is in TEXTO into the regex as a string.

Answer (score 43):

```
rx = r'\b(?<=\w){0}\b(?!\w)'.format(TEXTO)
```

Comment: Won't this be a problem if I'm using {4} in my regex to express I want exactly 4 of whatever comes before?

Answer (score 9):

I find it very convenient to build a regular expression pattern by stringing together multiple smaller patterns.

```
import re

string = "begin:id1:tag:middl:id2:tag:id3:end"
re_str1 = r'(?<=(\S{5})):'
re_str2 = r'(id\d+):(?=tag:)'
re_pattern = re.compile(re_str1 + re_str2)
match = re_pattern.findall(string)
print(match)
```

Output:

```
[('begin', 'id1'), ('middl', 'id2')]
```

Answer (score 6):

I agree with all the above unless:

`sys.argv[1]` was something like `Chicken\d{2}-\d{2}An\s*important\s*anchor`

```
sys.argv[1] = "Chicken\d{2}-\d{2}An\s*important\s*anchor"
```

you would not want to use `re.escape`, because in that case you would like it to behave like a regex

```
TEXTO = sys.argv[1]

if re.search(r"\b(?<=\w)" + TEXTO + "\b(?!\w)", subject, re.IGNORECASE):
    # Successful match
else:
    # Match attempt failed
```

Answer (score 4):

you can try another usage using `format` grammer suger:

```
re_genre = r'{}'.format(your_variable)
regex_pattern = re.compile(re_genre)
```

Answer (score 2):

I needed to search for usernames that are similar to each other, and what Ned Batchelder said was incredibly helpful. However, I found I had cleaner output when I used re.compile to create my re search term:

```
pattern = re.compile(r"("+username+".*):(.*?):(.*?):(.*?):(.*)"
matches = re.findall(pattern, lines)
```

Output can be printed using the following:

```
print(matches[1]) # prints one whole matching line (in this case, the first line)
print(matches[1][3]) # prints the fourth character group (established with the parentheses in the regex statement) of the first line.
```

Answer (score 1):

here's another format you can use (tested on python 3.7)

`regex_str = r'\b(?<=\w)%s\b(?!\w)'%TEXTO`

I find it's useful when you can't use `{}` for variable (here replaced with `%s`)

Answer (score 0):

You can use format keyword as well for this.Format method will replace {} placeholder to the variable which you passed to the format method as an argument.

```
if re.search(r"\b(?=\w)**{}**\b(?!\w)".**format(TEXTO)**, subject, re.IGNORECASE):
    # Successful match**strong text**
else:
    # Match attempt failed
```

Answer (score -1):

more example

I have configus.yml
with flows files

```
"pattern":
  - _(\d{14})_
"datetime_string":
  - "%m%d%Y%H%M%f"
```

in python code I use

```
data_time_real_file=re.findall(r""+flows[flow]["pattern"][0]+"", latest_file)
```