# Python regex:combining re pattern format with a variable

Tags: python, regex

I would like to combine a python variable and pattern. How can I do it?

below is what I would like to do.

```
re.search(r'**some_variable+pattern**',str_for_pattern_match,flags)
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: In fact I doubt that a regular expression beginning by two stars and ending by two stars is a valid one

Comment: As a note to answers just want to add - you need to pay close attention to variable value, as it could be treated as regexp things, giving wrong result after applying this regexp.

Comment: [**This question**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6930982/variable-inside-python-regex) is similar to yours. It may help you.

Answer (score 16):

The usual string formatting way works well

```
re.search(r'**%s+pattern**' % some_variable, str_for_pattern_match, flags)
```

Answer (score 7):

Regular expression patterns are not some special extra thing that Python treats specially. A pattern is just a perfectly ordinary string value, which the `re` module will interpret as a pattern.

So the question isn't "how can I use a variable in a pattern?", but rather "how can I construct a string based on a variable?".

The Python docs have plenty of information on how to do this. Particularly useful will be the documentation on [string methods](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#string-methods). The most important of these for the purpose of constructing regular expressions is probably will probably be `str.format` (as demonstrated in eumiro's answer), which has [a large section of its own](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#formatstrings) describing how to format basic data types into template strings in almost any way you could desire.

If you can master the basic operations on strings, then sticking a variable into a regular expression will be the least of what you can do!

Answer (score 6):

You have to be careful when inserting strings into a regexp pattern.

This is because the string may contain [special regexp characters](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax) which can lead to errors or give unexpected results.

To give an example:

```
>>> import re
>>> s = 'one*two*three*four*five'
>>> t = '*f'
>>> r = re.compile(r'%s\w+' % t)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/re.py", line 190, in compile
    return _compile(pattern, flags)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/re.py", line 244, in _compile
    raise error, v # invalid expression
sre_constants.error: nothing to repeat
```

This fails because the inserted string contains `*`, which is a special regexp character.

However, this problem can be dealt with by using the [`re.escape`](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.escape) function on the inserted string:

```
>>> r = re.compile(r'%s\w+' % re.escape(t))
>>> r.findall(s)
['*four', '*five']
```

Answer (score 5):

```
re.search(r'**{0}+pattern**'.format(variable_name), str_for_pattern_match, flags)
```

now all your `{…}` will be interpreted as [*string format*](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#format-string-syntax) placeholders.

Comment: One thing to note, though: if the variable has special metacharacters, they will be taken as is... If it is unwanted, one might want to surround the placeholder with `\Q` and `\E`: `r'\Q{0}\E'

Answer (score 2):

An update for using Python's `f-string` syntax (possibly the easiest of them all):

```
re.search(rf'**{some_variable}pattern**',str_for_pattern_match,flags)
```