# Python Regex in Variable

Tags: python, regex, exception

**Code Iteration #2**

Changing var1 to a raw string by using the `stringVar = r'string'` worked great.  With the code below I am now getting an exception of:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "regex_test.py", line 8, in <module>
    pattern = re.compile(var2 + "(.*)")
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/re.py", line 190, in compile
    return _compile(pattern, flags)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/re.py", line 242, in _compile
    raise error, v # invalid expression
sre_constants.error: unbalanced parenthesis
```

--

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import re

var1 = r'\\some\String\to\Match'
var2 = '\\\\some\\String\\'

pattern = re.compile(var2 + "(.*)")
found = pattern.match(var1, re.IGNORECASE)

if found:
    print "YES"
else:
    print "NO"
```

---

I am trying to include a variable in my regular expression.  This question is related to [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6930982/variable-inside-python-regex), but differs slightly by using a compiled pattern vs the variable within the match.  According to everything I've read, the example code below should work.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import re

var1 = re.escape('\\some\String\to\Match') # A windows network share
var2 = "\\\\some\\String\\"

print var1 # Prints \\some\\String\ o\\Match
print var2 # Prints \\some\String\

pattern = re.compile(var2)
found = pattern.match(var1 + "(.*)", re.IGNORECASE)

if found:
    print "YES"
else:
    print "NO"
```

When I print out my variables I am seeing some weird behavior.  I thought the re.escape would escape all needed chars within a string.

When I execute the code in Python 2.7 on Ubuntu 12.4.1 I get the following exception

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "regex_test.py", line 11, in <module>
    pattern = re.compile(var2)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/re.py", line 190, in compile
    return _compile(pattern, flags)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/re.py", line 242, in _compile
    raise error, v # invalid expression
sre_constants.error: bogus escape (end of line)
```

What am I missing that is causing the exception to be thrown?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`re.escape` is used for escaping a string to use as a regular expression, but you escape `var1` and then use `var2` as the regular expression.

I think the following is what you are trying to accomplish:

```
var1 = r'\\some\String\to\Match'
var2 = re.escape('\\\\some\\String\\')
pattern = re.compile(var2 + '(.*)', re.IGNORECASE)
found = pattern.match(var1)
```

Note that the `r'\\some\String\to\Match'` is a [raw string literal](http://docs.python.org/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals), but you cannot use it for `var2` since it needs to end in a backslash.

Comment: The end pattern should be \\some\String\(.*) which would should match var1 since I am getting any and all chars after the word 'String\'.  With the code provided, I am still getting the unbalanced parenthesis
exception when executing

Comment: The end pattern is what you pass into `re.compile`, you should the string you are trying to match into `pattern.match`.

Comment: @Wesley did you copy and paste my code exactly?  It should work fine.

Comment: I guess I somehow messed something up.  That worked perfectly.  Thank you

Answer (score 4):

Python's `\t` is a *single* character.  You might want to use `r''` (you can google 'raw string' to learn more) to avoid that problem.

The same is true of the `\` character.

To prove this, try printing the string inside `re.escape` before you feed it through.  It should make sense.

This is what you're looking for:

```
var1 = re.escape(r'\\some\String\to\Match')
```

Comment: Please see Code Iteration #2.  Using the raw string worked to get rid of the \t issue I was having

Comment: please `print` the value before you compile it and post it for us.  I'll bet you'll immediately know what you did wrong. (BTW: the value I want is: `var2 + '(.*)'`)

Answer (score 0):

`re.escape` does not make your life easier in this case:

```
In [68]: re.escape('\\\\some\\String\\')
Out[68]: '\\\\\\\\some\\\\String\\\\'

In [71]: re.escape(r'\\some\String\to\Match')

Out[71]: '\\\\\\\\some\\\\String\\\\to\\\\Match'
```

Clearly, there are too many backslashes there.

It is possible to do this with just raw strings:

```
In [62]: import re

In [63]: re.match(r'\\\\some\\String\\(.*)', r'\\some\String\to\Match').group(1)
Out[63]: 'to\\Match'
```