# Substring[whole word] check using a string variable

Tags: python, python-2.7, words, word-boundary

In Python`2.7`, I am trying the following:

```
 >>> import re
>>> text='0.0.0.0/0 172.36.128.214'
>>> far_end_ip="172.36.128.214"
>>>
>>>
>>> chk=re.search(r"\b172.36.128.214\b",text)
>>> chk
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x0000000002349578>
>>> chk=re.search(r"\b172.36.128.21\b",text)
>>> chk
>>> chk=re.search(r"\b"+far_end_ip+"\b",text)
>>>
>>> chk
>>>
```

Q:how can i make the search work when using the variable `far_end_ip`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two issues:

- You need to write the last bit of the string as a regex literal or escape the backslash: `... + r"\b"`
- You should escape the dots in the text to find: `... + re.escape(far_end_ip)`

So:

```
re.search(r"\b" + re.escape(far_end_ip) + r"\b",text)
```

See also ["How to use a variable inside a regular expression?"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6930982/5459839).