# write a regex for compile runtime keyword

Tags: python, regex

```
text = """ Pratap
pandey
age
25
student
"""
keyword = "age"

re_compile = re.compile('((.*\n+){2})keyword((.*\n+){2})')
re_result = re.findall(re_compile, text)
```

I want to write a regex for extracting two lines before keyword  and two lines after keyword when  keyword is matched, with variable.

Comment: Would you please add an example?

Comment: If i try with re_compile = re.compile('((.*\n+){2})age((.*\n+){2})'), then works, age instead of keyword, but i want to extract with variable name

Comment: I mean, an example of input and expected output.

Comment: I don't think this is possible, once compiled, the regex can't be modified. Instead you can use regex without compiling them before, modifying the string each time you change the keyword. This topic could help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6930982/how-to-use-a-variable-inside-a-regular-expression

Comment: @andrew input: Pratap pandey age 25 student, and if it founds keyword age then print line

Comment: I think your answer could be found in here: [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6930982/how-to-use-a-variable-inside-a-regular-expression)

Comment: @Pratap Was any of the answer helpful to you? Feel free to [upvote&accept](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely sure what you are asking. I think what you are trying to ask is how you put in the value of a variable named "keyword"

This is how you would do *that*

```
re.compile(f"(((.*\n+){{2}})\\s*{keyword}\\s*\n((.*\n+){{2}}))")
```

If you define keyword = <some value>, then the code above will work.

Btw. you need to use group 1 when extracting to get what you're looking for.

Comment: extract two lines before keyword and two lines after keyword when keyword is match

Answer (score 0):

**Possible Solution in Python 2.7**

You can use regular expressions uncompiled and put some string formatting in it.

```
from __future__ import print_function

import re

text = """ Pratap
pandey
age
25
student
"""
keywords = ("age", "else")

for key in keywords :
    print(re.findall(r'(.*\n+)(.*\n+){}\n+(.*\n+)(.*\n+)'.format(key), text))
```

Output:

```
[(' Pratap\n', 'pandey\n', '25\n', 'student\n')]
[]
```

(*) *Edited regular expression.*

Comment: thanks but didn't work. mine main problem is to extract two lines before keyword and two lines after keyword when keyword is match

Comment: @Pratap Then your regular expression may be incorrect... This will be the output of the whole: Two _identical_ lines before a keyword followed by _another two_ identical lines, e.g. `"abcdef\nabcdef\nKEY\nghijk\nghijk\n"`... if and only if `keyword = "KEY\n"`

Comment: @Pratap Have a look at my changes.

Answer (score 0):

To match two lines before and after the keyword use a regex like this:

```
(?:.*(?:\r?\n)+){2}age(?:.*(?:\r?\n|$)+){3}
```

[**Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/8OMPAr/1)

Explanation:

- `(?:.*(?:\r?\n|$)+){3}` actually, you need to match 3 of those blocks since the first newline is found directly after the keyword (`age`) and the next is found the end of line 4 (`25`). Therefore, a third repetition is needed.

However, since this could be the end of the string, I've added `$` as an alternative. I've also added an optional `\r` before `\n` which comes handy if your strings may contain Windows line endings, otherwise remove them.

[Sample code](https://ideone.com/8iILGX):

```
import re
regex = r"(?:.*(?:\r?\n)+){2}age(?:.*(?:\r?\n|$)+){3}"
test_str = (" Pratap\n"
    "pandey\n"
    "age\n"
    "25\n"
    "student")

matches = re.finditer(regex, test_str, re.MULTILINE)
for match in matches:
    matchNum = matchNum + 1    
    print (match.group())
```