# Python - Replace multiple character at once with .replace command

Tags: python

Is there any way to replace multiple different characters to another with a single *.replace* command?

Currently, I'm doing it once per line or through a loop:

```
    UserName = input("Enter in Username:")
    UserName = UserName.replace("/", "_")
    UserName = UserName.replace("?", "_")
    UserName = UserName.replace("|", "_")
    UserName = UserName.replace(":", "_")
    print(UserName)

    #Here's the second way- through a loop.
    Word = input("Enter in Example Word: ")
    ReplaceCharsList = list(input("Enter in replaced characters:"))

    for i in range(len(ReplaceCharsList)):
        Word = Word.replace(ReplaceCharsList[i],"X")
    print(Word)
```

Is there a *better* way to do this?

Comment: Look at regular expressions (standard library module `re`)

Comment: FYI, replace can be chained: `UserName = UserName.replace("/", "_").replace("?", "_").replace("|", "_").replace(":", "_")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub) with a regex that contains all the characters you want to replace:

```
import re

username = 'goku/?db:z|?'
print(re.sub(r'[/?|:]', '_', username))
# goku__db_z__
```

For the case where your user enters the characters to repalce, you can [build your regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6930982/how-to-use-a-variable-inside-a-regular-expression) as a string:

```
user_chars = 'abdf.#' # what you get from "input"
regex = r'[' + re.escape(user_chars) + ']'

word = 'baking.toffzz##'
print(re.sub(regex, 'X', word))
# XXkingXtoXXzzXX
```