# Regular expression function with iterable value in it

Tags: python, regex

So I have some `file`, and i need to check if certain words from my dic `Count` in certain lines of file.

I tried at first
`if Count[j+1] in file[i]:` 
and it didn't work, because for example word `a` from dictionary  will be triggered everywhere, and etc.

```
for i in range(lines_number):    
    for j in range(len(Count)):
        words_counter = 0
        if Count[j+1] in file[i]:
            words_counter += 1
```

So i tried to go on with regulars, but I don't know how to put `Count[j+1]` under regular expression.

```
for i in range(lines_number):    
    for j in range(len(Count)):
        words_counter = 0
        if len(re.findall(r '\b Count[j+1] \b', file[i]) > 0:
            words_counter += 1
```

**Sentence example:**

*In one, people deliberately tamed cats in a process of artificial selection, as they were useful predators of vermin.*

**Words from dic example:**

*cat, a, the*

Comment: what is your dictionary and please post an example

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use a variable inside a regular expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6930982/how-to-use-a-variable-inside-a-regular-expression)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In cases like this you should use [Literal String Interpolation](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/). So your code would look like -

```
for i in range(lines_number):    
    for j in range(len(Count)):
        words_counter = 0
        if len(re.findall(rf"\b {Count[j+1]} \b", file[i]) > 0:
            words_counter += 1
```

This specifically allows you to call your variables/lookups in the middle of `r''` strings.