# Python3 trying to use regular expression to match a pattern to a value in a variable

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm using Python3 and trying to use regular expression match a pattern to a value in a variable.  Before posting, I looked at:

[How to use variables in Python regular expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7580790/how-to-use-variables-in-python-regular-expression)

--and--

[How to use a variable inside a regular expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6930982/how-to-use-a-variable-inside-a-regular-expression)

Here's the code:

```
import re

x = []

x.append("test")
x.append("me")
x.append(x[0] + x[1])

TEXTO = x[2]

print(TEXTO)

if re.search(rf"\b(?=\w){TEXTO}\b(?!\w)", "StM", re.IGNORECASE):
    print("Successful match")
else:
    print("Match attempt failed")

if re.search('(.+)'+TEXTO+'(.+)', "StM", re.IGNORECASE):
    print("Successful match")
else:
    print("Match attempt failed")
```

and it's still failing.  Both outputs received are "Match attempt failed"

```
[dogzilla@localhost ~]$ python3 py1.py 
testme
Match attempt failed
Match attempt failed
```

What is the proper way to put the variable in question (TEXTO) in the search method?

Thanks!

Comment: What do you expect each of the regexs to be? Do you expect them to match the string `'StM'`?

Comment: I can't really tell what you're trying to do--so i wont touch much-- but I think you mixed up your pattern and your search. Maybe try  `re.search('(.+)'+"stM"+'(.+)', TEXTO, re.IGNORECASE)` . I am assuming `TEXTO` is the TextToSearch (which is the second argument). And `sTM` looks like some pattern

Comment: Both ways are proper to put the variable into a string. But you need to decide what is your pattern to search and what is your string to search the pattern in. Because now it looks mixed up.

Comment: The I'm inspecting a variable.  TEXTO.  Inside of TEXTO is "testme".  I want to match on "StM"... which are the 3rd, 4th, and 5th characters and should return true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the order of your parameters:

```py
if re.search('StM', TEXTO, re.IGNORECASE):
    print("Successful match")
else:
    print("Match attempt failed")
```