# Abstract regular expressions

Tags: python, sql, regex, nlp

I am working on processing queries in russian language (translating them into SQL code to be executed). I tokenize the query, do morphological analysis, from lemmas I get links to database objects. So now I want to use patterns like regular expressions to get things like conditions, `ORDER BY` expressions and so on. But the thing is, regex can only be used with list of characters (strings).

Is there a library/solution for Python (preferably) which works like regular expressions but for any kinds of objects (list of tokens with grammatical properties or database objects), not just strings?

So, as an example, I want to write patterns which would look something this:

```
[db-column]((','|'and')[db-column])*
```

this pattern would match a list of database objects like this: columnA, columnB and columnC.

Comment: regex works only on characters. So, you need to convert any object to a string first before applying regex. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6930982/how-to-use-a-variable-inside-a-regular-expression) is how to use variables into regex python.

Comment: But that way I'd have to convert to string the whole object which may make the query string quite large and the regex patterns would be quite ugly and cumbersome.

Comment: Sadly, that's the only way I think

Comment: What about replacing `[db-column]` in the input regex with some pattern? Like `\w+` or `(?:columnA|columnB|...)`, and then run it as a regex?

Comment: Well, that's just a simple example. Some patterns may require different properties of objects, like type of the object (database column, table, or a regular word, like a verb or a preposition etc.) or grammatical case, is it plural or not and so on.

Answer (score 1):

If someone is interested in the topic, there is a [GitHub repository with my work](https://github.com/Ruminat/Asq-Server), I wrote the following code for Abstract regular expressions:

```py
"""
  AbstractRegularExpressions.py
  
  Abstract Regular Expressions.
  They are like regular expressions, but can work with any kinds of objects,
  not just characters as in regex.
  This code is based on Mark-Jason Dominus's article «How Regexes Work»,
  you can find it here: https://perl.plover.com/Regex/article.html
"""

# NFA - Nondeterministic Finite Automata (machine).

# Used for defining custom operators.
# http://code.activestate.com/recipes/384122/
class Infix:
  def __init__(self, function):
    self.function = function
  def __ror__(self, other):
    return Infix(lambda x, self=self, other=other: self.function(other, x))
  def __or__(self, other):
    return self.function(other)
  def __rlshift__(self, other):
    return Infix(lambda x, self=self, other=other: self.function(other, x))
  def __rshift__(self, other):
    return self.function(other)
  def __call__(self, value1, value2):
    return self.function(value1, value2)

# Alternatives («|» in regex): a|b|c (in regex) <==> a |OR| b |OR| c (here). 
class Cases:
  def __init__(self, cases):
    self.cases = cases
  def add(self, case):
    self.cases.append(case)
    return self
# Operator for joining cases, used like this: a |OR| b |OR| c.
OR = Infix(lambda x, y: x.add(y) if isinstance(x, Cases) else Cases([x, y]))

# Primitives are used to test one token for some predicate.
# In regex there's only one primitive — whether a token is equal to some character or not.
# Examples of primitives: «is token a table column?», «is token's type — string» etc.
class Primitive:
  def __init__(self, name, predicate):
    self.predicate = predicate
    self.name = name
  def test(self, *args):
    return self.predicate(*args)
  def __str__(self):
    return self.name

# Transitions are the arrows in NFAs,
# one transition leads from one state to another if the pattern's condition is met for a token.
# If there is no pattern (pattern = None), then you can always go to the next state (epsilon-transition).
class Transition:
  def __init__(self, pattern, nextState=None):
    self.pattern = pattern
    self.nextState = nextState

stateID = 0 # Only used for pretty-printing Patterns (machines).
# State is just a bunch of transitions leading to other states or the final state (None).
class State:
  def __init__(self, transitions):
    global stateID
    stateID += 1
    self.ID = stateID
    self.transitions = transitions
  def __str__(self):
    return str(self.ID)

# Recursively creates an NFA
# (makes simple NFAs from primitives and then connects them with connectMachines).
def makeMachine(pattern):
  # Subpatterns are treated the same as primitives.
  if (isinstance(pattern, Pattern) or isinstance(pattern, Primitive)):
    return State({ Transition(pattern) })
  # Make a machine out of each member of a list and then connect them with connectMachines.
  elif (isinstance(pattern, list)):
    if (len(pattern) == 0): return None
    accMachine = makeMachine(pattern[-1])
    for i in range(1, len(pattern)):
      accMachine = connectMachines(makeMachine(pattern[-1 - i]), accMachine)
    return accMachine
  # Quantifiers (+, ?, *).
  elif (isinstance(pattern, tuple)):
    (p, quantifier) = pattern
    machine = makeMachine(p)
    if (quantifier == '+' or quantifier == '*'):
      endTransitions = []
      for state in statesIterator(machine, set()):
        for transition in state.transitions:
          if transition.nextState == None:
            endTransitions.append((state, transition))
      for (state, transition) in endTransitions:
        transition.nextState = machine
        state.transitions.add(Transition(transition.pattern, None))
    if (quantifier == '?' or quantifier == '*'):
      if (len([m for m in machine.transitions if m.pattern == None and m.nextState == None]) == 0):
        machine.transitions.add(Transition(None))
    return machine
  # For cases (a |OR| b |OR| c).
  elif (isinstance(pattern, Cases)):
    return combineMachines([makeMachine(p) for p in pattern.cases])

# Goes through each state of a machine.
def statesIterator(state, passedStates = set()):
  if (state != None): yield state
  else: return
  passedStates.add(state)
  for transition in state.transitions:
    if (not transition.nextState in passedStates):
      for s in statesIterator(transition.nextState, passedStates):
        yield s

# Connects two machines into one (replaces finish states of machineA with start states of machineB).
def connectMachines(machineA, machineB):
  endTransitions = []
  for state in statesIterator(machineA, set()):
    for transition in state.transitions:
      if transition.nextState == None:
        endTransitions.append(transition)
  for transition in endTransitions:
    transition.nextState = machineB
  return machineA

# Connects cases of machines (machineA |OR| machineB |OR| ... |OR| machineN) into one machine.
def combineMachines(machines):
  return State({ t for machine in machines for t in machine.transitions })

# Pattern, as in regular expressions.
# Example: p = Pattern('name', [a, b, c, (d, '+') |OR| e])
# which gives you a regex «abc(d+|e)»,
# where a, b, c, d and e are another patterns or primitives.
class Pattern:
  def __init__(self, name, pattern):
    global stateID
    stateID = 0
    self.name = name
    self.machine = makeMachine(pattern)
  def __str__(self):
    return self.name

# Structure stores tokens of a found pattern.
class Structure:
  def __init__(self, name, elements=None):
    self.name = name
    self.elements = elements if elements != None else []
  def __str__(self):
    return f' --- {self.name} --- {[str(el) for el in self.elements]}'

# Class for storing a token and pattern which found this token.
class PatternToken:
  def __init__(self, pattern, token):
    self.pattern = pattern
    self.token = token
  def __str__(self):
    return f'{self.pattern}: {self.token.text}'

# Used for storing linked matched tokens.
class CurrentState:
  def __init__(self, token, transition=None, previousState=None, patternsStack=[]):
    self.transition = transition
    self.token = token
    self.previousState = previousState
    self.patternsStack = patternsStack
  def __str__(self):
    t = self.token.text if self.token != None else ''
    return f'== [{self.transition.pattern.name} ({len(self.patternsStack)}): {t}]\n{self.previousState}'
  # Connects linked CurrentStates into one Structure.
  def connect(self, name):
    state = self
    structuresStack = []
    result = []
    indexes = []
    while True:
      token = state.token
      transition = state.transition
      # Pattern
      if (isinstance(transition.pattern, Pattern)):
        if (len(structuresStack) == 0 or structuresStack[-1].name != transition.pattern.name):
          structuresStack.append(Structure(transition.pattern.name))
        else:
          structure = structuresStack.pop()
          structure.elements = structure.elements[::-1] # reverse the elements.
          if (len(structuresStack) == 0):
            result.append(structure)
          else:
            structuresStack[-1].elements.append(structure)
      # Primitive
      elif (isinstance(transition.pattern, Primitive)):
        indexes.append(token.index)
        if (len(structuresStack) == 0):
          result.append(PatternToken(transition.pattern, token))
        else:
          structuresStack[-1].elements.append(PatternToken(transition.pattern, token))
      state = state.previousState
      if (state == None): break
    return ((min(indexes), max(indexes)), Structure(name, result[::-1]))

# Used for running a pattern on a list of tokens.
class Automata:
  def __init__(self, pattern):
    self.pattern = pattern
    self.finalStates = set()
    self.currentStates = set()
  def feedToken(self, token):
    currentStates = set(self.currentStates)
    self.currentStates = set()
    for state in currentStates:
      for transition in state.transition.nextState.transitions:
        self.processTransition(transition, token, state)
    for transition in self.pattern.machine.transitions:
      self.processTransition(transition, token)
  def __str__(self):
    return "\n\n".join([str(state) for state in self.finalStates])
  def processTransition(self, transition, token, previousState=None):
    # Epsilon
    if (transition.pattern == None):
      if (transition.nextState != None):
        for t in transition.nextState.transitions:
          self.processTransition(t, token, previousState)
      elif (len(previousState.patternsStack) == 0):
        self.finalStates.add(previousState)
      else:
        newState = previousState
        while True:
          patternsStack = list(newState.patternsStack)
          patternState = patternsStack.pop()
          newState = CurrentState(None, patternState.transition, newState, patternsStack)
          if (newState.transition.nextState != None):
            for t in newState.transition.nextState.transitions:
              self.processTransition(t, token, newState)
            break
          if (len(newState.patternsStack) == 0):
            self.finalStates.add(newState)
            break
    # Primitive
    elif (isinstance(transition.pattern, Primitive)):
      if (transition.pattern.test(token)):
        patternsStack = previousState.patternsStack if previousState != None else []
        newState = CurrentState(token, transition, previousState, list(patternsStack))
        if (newState.transition.nextState != None):
          self.currentStates.add(newState)
        elif (len(newState.patternsStack) == 0):
          self.finalStates.add(newState)
        else:
          while True:
            patternsStack = list(newState.patternsStack)
            patternState = patternsStack.pop()
            newState = CurrentState(None, patternState.transition, newState, patternsStack)
            if (newState.transition.nextState != None):
              self.currentStates.add(newState)
              break
            if (len(newState.patternsStack) == 0):
              self.finalStates.add(newState)
              break
    # Pattern
    elif (isinstance(transition.pattern, Pattern)):
      patternsStack = previousState.patternsStack if previousState != None else []
      newState = CurrentState(None, transition, previousState, list(patternsStack))
      newState.patternsStack.append(newState)
      for t in transition.pattern.machine.transitions:
        self.processTransition(t, token, newState)

# Pretty-print a machine.
def printMachine(machine):
  padding = 0
  for state in statesIterator(machine, set()):
    for t in state.transitions:
      print(padding*' ' + f'{state}: --{t.pattern}->{t.nextState}')
    padding += 1

# Pretty-print a pattern.
def printPattern(pattern):
  print(f'-=-=-=-=-= {pattern.name} =-=-=-=-=-')
  printMachine(pattern.machine)
```

Which allows you to write templates like these:

```py
# Selecting
table = Primitive('table', lambda token: token.type == 'table')
column = Primitive('column', lambda token: token.type == 'column')
columnExpr = Pattern('columnExpr', [(operator, '*'), column])
columnLiteralExpr = Pattern('columnExpr', [(operator, '*'), column |OR| literal])
listOfTables = Pattern('listOfTables', [table])
listOfColumns = Pattern('listOfColumns', [columnExpr, ([connector, columnExpr], '*'), (table, '?')])
selectExpr = Pattern('selectExpr', [listOfColumns |OR| listOfTables])
```