# Using fuzzy regex with variable while still specifying error

Tags: python, regex

I'm using the [regex](https://pypi.org/project/regex/) library in python and trying to do fuzzy matching.

I need to use a variable in my search string and this is the code I got following [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6930982/how-to-use-a-variable-inside-a-regular-expression)

```
x = regex.search(rf"(?b){variable}{d}",s)
```

which gives `NameError: name 'd' is not defined`

The issue is that I want to specify the type of error with the `{d}` tag but that is also interpreted as a variable. The only solution I have come up with so far is just to assign `d = "d"`. Looking for a more "proper" way to accomplish this.

Example case:

```
variable = "amazing"
s = 'amaing analogy'
x = regex.search(rf"{variable}{d}",s)
x.group()
```

intended output : "amaing"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can escape the currently brackets by adding another currently brackets

```
x = regex.search(rf"(?b){variable}{{d}}",s)
```

Comment: @zhao @leo what is this `d` syntax? I can't find any good documentation or examples on how to use error tag `{e<=1}` or `{e<=.97}` type examples.