# Using an enumeration in the join command - python

Tags: python, enums

python 3.8.2 :

I have tried to get a string, created with `join` from an `enum`.

```
import enum

# import aenum
# https://pypi.org/project/aenum/


class ELEMENTS(enum.Enum):
    L = ("L", "light", "licht")
    P = ("P", "power connectors", "stopcontacten")
    vM = ("vM", "ventilation motor", "ventilatie motor")
    cvM = ("cvM", "CV motor", "CV motor")
    S = ("S", "switch", "schakelaar")
    V = ("V", "valve", "klep")


ELEMENTS_list = []
print(len(ELEMENTS))
for s in ELEMENTS:
    ELEMENTS_list.append(s.value[0])

regexELEMENTS = "[" + ("|".join(ELEMENTS_list)) + "]"
```

returns, as result :

> [L|P|vM|cvM|S|V]

**Update on feedback of 'VPfB' - thanks**

```
regexELEMENTS = "(" + ("|".join(ELEMENTS_list)) + ")"
```

returns, the wanted result :

> (L|P|vM|cvM|S|V)

By my humble opinion the code would be more proper, if I could do it immediately from the enum.

...

```
print("|".join(ELEMENTS.value[0]))
```

returns error :

```
... in __getattr__
raise AttributeError(name) from None
```

an other approach :

```
print("|".join(ELEMENTS))
```

returns error :

```
TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, ELEMENTS found
```

In the second step I'll use the variable 'regexELEMENTS' in a regular expression. '{regexELEMENTS}'

Based on this question :
[How to use a variable inside a regular expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6930982/how-to-use-a-variable-inside-a-regular-expression)

What I'm missing here ... or do I wrong?

Hope to understand, what I'm doing wrong ...

Suggestions to make the code better are more then welcome.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if you want to use the names or the `value[0]` strings which happen to be the same in your example. Choose one:

```
print("|".join(ELEMENTS.__members__))  # using names
```

or:

```
print("|".join(m.value[0] for m in ELEMENTS))   # using value[0]
```

This answer is based mainly on [enum iteration docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#iteration). I have omitted `[` and `]` for brevity (BTW, I think you want `(` and `)` to build an usable regexp)

Comment: Thank you very much ... for loops in one line.
And correctly it has to be `(` and `)` instead of `[` and `]`

`print("|".join(ELEMENTS.__members__))  # using names` is the best way ***. I have already deleted the first index `ELEMENTS.value[0]` in my code.

Comment: I'm glad I could help. The "for loops in one line" have an official name: https://docs.python.org/3/howto/functional.html#generator-expressions-and-list-comprehensions

Comment: Dear @VPfB, thanks for the answer ... I just have read your profile "I'm the author of a free open-source Python library that has zero users except me.)" ...  **unknown is unloved**. So would you be so kind ... to add it in your profile ... maybe there a lot of members which are looking for such kind of library ...

Comment: @kris Oh, my library ... well, thanks for asking, but it is not hidden. It is available on github and on PyPi for more than a year and it really looks like nobody needs it. Judge yourself, the name is "edzed".