# How to search for a pattern that contains a variable using regex in python?

Tags: python, regex

I have multiple files, each containing multiple strings like this one:

```
Species_name_ID:0.0000010229,
```

I need to find the string with a specific 'Species_name_ID', that I ask the user to provide, and do a simple replacement so that it now reads:

```
Species_name_ID:0.0000010229 #1,
```

I'm stuck at the first part, trying to look for the pattern. I've tried looking only for the numeric pattern at the end with this, and it returns a list of all the instances in which the pattern appears:

```
my_regex = r':0\.\d{10}'
for line in input_file:
        sp = re.findall(my_regex, line)
print(sp)
```

However, when I try adding the rest by using the string the user provides, it doesn't work and returns an empty list.

```
search = input("Insert the name of the species: ")
my_regex = f"{search}:0\.\d{{10}}"
for line in input_file:
        sp = re.findall(my_regex, line)
print(sp)
```

I've also tried the following syntax for defining the variable (all come from this previous question [How to use a variable inside a regular expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6930982/how-to-use-a-variable-inside-a-regular-expression)):

```
my_regex = f"{search}"
my_regex = f"{search}" + r':0\.\d{10}'
my_regex = search + r':0\.\d{10}'
my_regex = re.compile(re.escape(search) + r':0\.\d{10}')
my_regex = r'%s:0\.\d{10}'%search
my_regex = r"Drosophila_melanogaster_12215" + r':0\.\d{10}'
```

Even when I try searching for the specified string, it doesn't find it in the file even when there are multiple hits it could make.

```
my_regex = Drosophila_melanogaster_12215
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Do you realize you re-write `sp` upon each line with `for line in input_file:   sp = re.findall(my_regex, line)`?

Comment: I am, but it should not matter. My files only have one line. When I try the code that works, I get a list of 19 numbers, which is what I have in the file.

Comment: You need to use a raw f-string so that the backslashes will be preserved, for the same reason you used a raw string in the first code block.

Comment: `my_regex = search + r':0\.\d{10}'` should work, though.

Comment: `my_regex = re.escape(search) + r':0\.\d{10}'` cannot fail to work.

Comment: Do you mean,  ```my_regex = f'{search}'```? It doesn't work either.

Comment: No, I meant `my_regex = rf"{search}:0\.\d{{10}}"`

Comment: The version with `re.escape()` is best and works: https://ideone.com/a0vPcJ

Comment: Alright, what Barmar suggested worked! Thanks for helping me figure out that I was writing the syntax correctly. However, it still doesn't work if I use the ```input_file``` variable instead of ```line```. I think I can work it out from there.

Answer (score 0):

This must work for you:

```py
import re
search = input("Insert the name of the species: ")
my_regex = fr"{re.escape(search)}:0\.\d{{10}}"
for line in input_file:
    print( re.findall(my_regex, line) )
```

Escape the user-defined variable placed inside regular expressions.

Double curly braces if you want curly braces inside.

Use raw string literal for your regular expressions.